# Langsmith is incorrectly tracing tokens

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, langsmith

I have a simple langgraph chain in place and I noticed that the counting of tokens is oddly off in langsmith in comperison to OpenAI online tokenizer or Python tokenizer:

Langsmith tokens (2,067):
[image]

Python program:

```
import tiktoken

def num_tokens_from_string(string: str) -> int:
    encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding("cl100k_base")
    num_tokens = len(encoding.encode(string))
    return num_tokens

test_string = """ Ctrl+c ctrl+v from langsmith trace """
print(num_tokens_from_string(test_string))
```

Output:
11185

OpenAI tokenizer:
[image]

Question:

1. Why are the token counts different for langsmith and OpenAI?
2. How do I send / set in Langsmith correct counting token methods? For this python code: `response = ChatOpenAI().invoke("Hello!")`